# Best Practice To Manage Laravel 5.4 API With Existing Web

Tags: angular, laravel-5, vuejs2

I'm working on an e-commerce project using **laravel-vue** for web site and **laravel-api** for mobile application, I wanted suggestion on the best way to manage **API part** or the best way to implement the project.

These are my thoughts on implementing this:

1->using same controller for both **API** and **web**, but worried abut complex logic and scalability

```
public function index(Request $request) 
{
    $users = User::all();

    if ($request->wantsJson()) {
        //return json-data for mobile app
    }

    return view('agents', compact('users'));
}
```

2->creating separate `namespace` for API controllers. `namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\;`

3->creating just the API using laravel and create client app using vue-cli/angular2 so that the mobile app and web app can use the same API. **Here concerned about SEO**.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to move all your buisness logic to some special classes, lets call'em services. So you will have an ability to use same logic in different parts of your application.

You definitely should separate you controllers to API controllers and web controllers. So you will have an ability to use different middlewares for API and WEB parts.

As example you may have API in connection with some frontend single page application and WEB for admin dashboard (where you don't need SPA) but use same services (without any code duplication).